# How to use bound values in a components controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component that looks like this:

```
var meadow = angular.module('meadow');

meadow.component('productIncome', {
    bindings: {
        product: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/static/js/app/product-detail/product-income/product-income.html',
    controller: function () {
        var vm = this;

        console.log(vm.product)
    }
})
```

Now I want to make us of the product that's bound to the component, but it's telling me that "vm.product is undefined". I've tried using $onInit but it still produces the same results. For $onInit it did :

```
 vm.$onInit = function(){
      console.log(vm.product)
 }
```

product-income.html

```
<product-income product="$ctrl.products.product"></product-income>
```

How can I get this working? Thanks

Comment: What is `products.product`? I guess that `products` is collection. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it is. It has a different controller.

Comment: If so, then you need to iterate by this collection, like: `<product-income ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.products" product="product"></product-income>`

Answer (score 0):

I made a working demo here:

```js
var meadow = angular.module('meadow', []);
meadow = meadow.controller("abc", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = {
    product: "a"
  }
});
meadow.component('productIncome', {
  bindings: {
    product: '='
  },
  template: "<div></div>",
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.$onChanges = function() {
      console.log("onchange", vm.product);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("timeout", vm.product);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="meadow" ng-controller="abc">
  <product-income product="products.product"></product-income>
</div>
```

So it seems that the order of the controllers are not sure, u should make a async to get the value, or use "$onChanges " to listen to the value.